# R: generate all unique permutations from a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector in which certain entries are repeated. From this vector, I want to obtain every possible and unique permutations.

Looking around, I saw that `gtools::permutations()` was recommended a few times but it cannot solve my issue.

I found a way with `RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral()` but the problem is that it treats every entry as a unique value and then I have to remove the duplicates in a second step. This can cause memory issue.

Is there a simple and fast way to get all the unique permutations from a vector?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(RcppAlgos)
ex <- c("sp1", "sp2", "sp2") # sp2 is repeated twice

perm <- permuteGeneral(v = ex, m = length(ex), repetition = FALSE, freqs = NULL)
perm <- as.data.frame(perm)
perm # some rows are identical (rows 1&2; 3&5, 4&6)
   V1  V2  V3
1 sp1 sp2 sp2
2 sp1 sp2 sp2
3 sp2 sp1 sp2
4 sp2 sp2 sp1
5 sp2 sp1 sp2
6 sp2 sp2 sp1

perm[!duplicated(perm), ] # this is what I want
   V1  V2  V3
1 sp1 sp2 sp2
3 sp2 sp1 sp2
4 sp2 sp2 sp1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
library(RcppAlgos)

tab <- table(ex)
permuteGeneral(v = names(tab), freq = tab)
##      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
## [1,] "sp1" "sp2" "sp2"
## [2,] "sp2" "sp1" "sp2"
## [3,] "sp2" "sp2" "sp1"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `unique` + `perms`

```
> unique(pracma::perms(ex))
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] "sp2" "sp2" "sp1"
[2,] "sp2" "sp1" "sp2"
[3,] "sp1" "sp2" "sp2"
```

---

or we can do like this

```
permuteGeneral(
  v = unique(ex),
  m = length(ex),
  freqs = table(ex)
)
```

which gives

```
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] "sp1" "sp2" "sp2"
[2,] "sp2" "sp1" "sp2"
[3,] "sp2" "sp2" "sp1"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is basically doing the same than what I tried with `RcppAlgos` but I tried on a longer character and `pracma` seems slower.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just accepted @G.Grothendieck answer.

Comment: @P.Denelle No worries :) G.Grothendieck's answer is more concise.